# Disable autocomplete for parentheses in Teradata Studio Express

Tags: sql, windows, teradata

How can I disable inserting matching parentheses SQL Editor query window. When I enter only left one "(" it automatically inserts right one ")". Is there any way do disable it. It's not happening when I insert braces "{}" nor brackets "[]".

I'm using Teradata Studio Express version:17.00.12.00.202012260107. On Windows 10 1909.

Comment: SQL Editor preferences, Typing tab.

Comment: I don't have that option in SQL Editor Preference, only "Enable syntax validation" check box.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Editor preferences customize the behaviors and look-and-feel of the SQL Editor. To set preferences for general editor appearance and behaviors, go to Window > Preferences > Data Management > SQL Development > SQL Editor.